# Fallout 4 robot build poster DLC foreshadowing?

Tags: fallout-4

I can't remember where I saw it, and I've scraped the bsa files, but I can't find it anywhere.

I clearly remember there being a poster or wall hanging in a lab somewhere that showed all the kinds of robots.

Protectron, Handy, Sentry, and a Synth-like robot.

And it showed a bunch of pictures that looked like the results of a body flip book. One drawing had a sentry legs with a synth torso, protectron legs with sentry torso, and so on.

I thought it was interesting but didn't screenshot.

Then the DLC comes out, and I wondered if they dropped that poster as foreshadowing the DLC.

I've retraced my steps everywhere and can't find this poster...

Did anyone else see it?

EDIT: Thanks to the answer, I found it.

[image]

Comment: What are you actually asking? If a certain poster exists? In-game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the switchboard. in the room opposite the corridor that leads to the vault. Its on the wall straight ahead as you walk through the door.

Comment: ZOMG thanks... will look for it.

I swear, I heard of the DLC and thought, that was a spoiler for sure.

Comment: Found it. Definitely what I remember it being. Given that one of the options in the preview is a sentry legs with a handy torso/head, and that option is on the poster, I'm definitely convinced that this was intended.